# Disable hidden backup files in Word (~$somefilename.doc)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

Whenever you open a word doc, a copy of some sort gets created, in the same folder.  it is renamed like somedocument.doc -> ~$medocument.doc  and it is 'hidden' ie, ghosted out.

How do I stop Word from creating the file?  I dont care autosaving or backup recovery.  If disabling is not possible, is it possible to make it save in my temp folder or other out of the way place?

I also *do not want* to know how to turn off visibility of hidden files, in explorer.

Comment: I don't think you can. It's a "lock file" so that if a second copy of the document is opened Word knows to open it read-only.

Comment: I believe this is how Word works so such files cannot be disabled. However, they all should be deleted once you close the original files.